# Using Python's aiohttp to make a web request, I'm getting a browser out of date error?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to use the `aynscio` and `aiohttp` packages to request a web page. However, the web page response is:

```
<p class="warning-title"> Please upgrade your web browser. </p>  <br/>
<p class="p-top-30">This browser version is outdated, and may not be fully compatible with our website. Please upgrade to a newer version or use another browser.    </p>
```

It doesn't actually load the page I'm trying to access but the homepage instead.

**CODE**

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import ssl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio
import aiohttp

ua = UserAgent()

hdr = {'User-Agent': str(ua.chrome),
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_ctx.check_hostname = False
ssl_ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = '...'

async def parse_website(session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        html = await response.text()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    print(soup)

async with asyncio.Semaphore(3):
    async with aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_ctx, limit=None) as connector:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=hdr) as session:
            for i in range(1):
                await parse_website(session)
```

I have tried not including the `headers` argument in the third to last line `async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:` but then the response is that I didn't wait long enough for the captcha. So I have to use the `headers` argument to bypass the captcha but I consistently get a `Please upgrade your browser` response. I also tried adding `cookies={}` to the same line `async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, headers=hdr, cookies={}) as session:` but get the same original response saying the browser is out of date.

I'm also only showing one url request here. Once I have this working I'll scale to thousands, so that's why I'm trying to make this work with the `asyncio` and `aiohttp` packages.

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: what is the response code you are getting? Which site do you want to access? Are you sure they are not preventing it in some way?

Comment: I was using `connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)` maybe that helps

Comment: Your issue is most likely with your `url`, and not so much so with Python. Impossible for any of us to debug it without knowing the website you are trying to scrape.